# Simple field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension of degree $n$ and $\vartheta\in L$. Further let there exist $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\in\text{Aut}_K(L)$ with $\sigma_i(\vartheta)\neq \sigma_j(\vartheta)$ for $i\neq j$. Then I want to show that $\vartheta$ is primitive for $L/K$, e.g. that $L=K(\vartheta)$.

Do you have any hints? I know that zeros are send to zeros by any automorphism, but I dont know that there exist an element $\lambda$ with $L=K(\lambda)$, or do I? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $K$ is perfect you know that such a $\lambda$ exists; so in general you don't. But can you try to calculate $[K(\vartheta):K]$ by using the minimal polynomial of $\vartheta$ over $K$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\vartheta$ over $K$. 
As you say, an automorphism fixing $K$ preserves the property of being a zero of a polynomial over $K$, so each $\sigma_i(\vartheta)$ is a root of $f$. 
Hence, degree of $\,\vartheta\ =\,$ degree of $f\ \ge n$.